# Android chat SDK fragment error

Tags: android, sdk, fragment, chat

I'm using the Zendesk Zopim Android Chat SDK. When I try to open the chat screen as a fragment (like here: http://bit.ly/1hOkyce) I get the following error:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.zopim.android.sdk.prechat.ZopimChatFragment', required: 'android.app.Fragment'
```

When I open the ZopimChatFragment class, it still extends from Fragment so I don't understand why it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
ZopimChatFragment fragment = new ZopimChatFragment();
android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment, ZopimChatFragment.class.getName()); // it's the second argument from this line
transaction.commit();
```

The class ZopimChatFragment class starts with the following:

```
public class ZopimChatFragment extends Fragment {...}
```

So if it extends Fragment, then why does the error say it requires a Fragment instead of a ZopimChatFragment? With all my other Fragment replacements, I use the class name too instead of "Fragment".

**EDIT**

I followed ρяσѕρєя K's instructions, now I get an error in the HomeActivity where I replace the fragment.

```
final Fragment fragmentName;
        switch (position) {
        ....
        case 3:
        Fragment fragment3 = new ChatFragment();
        fragmentName = null;
        break;
        ....

@Override
public void run() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.mainContent, fragmentName)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Close the drawer

        }
        }, 300);
```

The error says it requires a Fragment instead of a ChatFragment

Answer (score 1):

As in `build.gradle` of provided sample code.  library is using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.+'` dependencies. means they are using Fragment from support library instead of default.

so use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` for getting `FragmentManager`:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
```

Comment: I changed those two lines into yours but it says "required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, found android.app.FragmentManager"; on the first line

Comment: @Helix: remove  all imports which is starting with `android.app.*`  import from imports. then try it

Comment: The situation gets kind of complicated now. The code from the ChatFragment class seems to work now. The problem is that I'm replacing the HomeActivity fragment with the ChatFragment, so now I get an error in HomeActivity saying that it needs a Fragment instead of a ChatFragment. I'll add more information about it in an edit in the main post.

Comment: @Helix: do same in `HomeActivity` which u have done for `ZopimChatFragment` fragment ans also make sure in ur whole application you are using fragment from support library instead of from `android.app.*` package

Answer (score 0):

I never used this library but replace the following:

```
android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
```

with

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

I suggest you to follow the documentation:

```
import com.zopim.android.sdk.chatlog.ZopimChatLogFragment;
...
ZopimChatFragment fragment = new ZopimChatFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.chat_fragment_container, fragment, ZopimChatFragment.class.getName());
transaction.commit();
...
```

Comment: I get an error on getSupportFragmentManager that it's undefined. Note that the fragment that is going to be replaced extends from android.app.Fragment, not from  android.support.v4.